# Is it possible to skip "empty" values/categories in facets in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Let's say I have this kind of data:

```
set.seed(42)
type<-c("a","b","c","a","a","a","a","b","b","c","a","b")
code<-as.factor(c(rep(1:3,4)))
result<-(runif(12)*10)

data<-data.frame(type, code, result)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = code, y = result, fill = code, shape = code )) +
         geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5)+
         geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.76), size = 3)+
         facet_wrap(~type, nrow = 1)
```

Which results in this graph created by ggplot2, where data is facetted by "type" column:
[image: graph facetted by "type" column]

There are "empty" categories in facets "b" (no values for "1") and "c" (no values for "2"). I'm wondering whether it's possible somehow to skip this missing values/categories in those facets and show only the categories that have values for this specific facet ? Meaning, "a" would contain all three boxplots as have data for all of them, "b" would contain two boxplots for "2" and "3", no code "1" parameter in this facet as it's empty, "c" would contain boxplot for "1" and "3", no code "2" parameter in this facet.

Thank you!

Comment: add ```scales = "free"``` to the facet_wrap

Comment: @Silentdevildoll: You probably meant `scales="free_x"`.

Comment: I've always just used ```free```, but @stefan you are right in that ```"free_x"``` would be more direct, only affecting the one scale rather than both scales. Accuracy is important, so thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! That's what I was looking for ! Thank you!